# Access Character Motor from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to create a run script. Access the player's CharacterMotor and increase the movement speeds but the compiler is saying the objects don't exist.
Using the stock Fisrt Person Character Controller

error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for`CharacterMotor' and no extension method `CharacterMotor' of type`UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public class PlayerRun : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject _player;
private float _runSpeed = 10;
private float _defaultSpeed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    _defaultSpeed = _player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxForwardSpeed;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        _player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxForwardSpeed = _runSpeed;
        _player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxSidewaysSpeed = _runSpeed;
        _player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxBackwardsSpeed = _runSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
        if (_player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxForwardSpeed == _runSpeed)
        {
            _player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxForwardSpeed = _defaultSpeed;
        _player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxSidewaysSpeed = _defaultSpeed;
        _player.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").CharacterMotor.maxBackwardsSpeed = _defaultSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you drag-drop the _player instance in the Inspector or otherwise make sure that _player is set when the script runs?

Comment: added the error. I get: ype UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition forCharacterMotor' and no extension method CharacterMotor' of typeUnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). The script wont even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've just moved from UnityScript to C#?

You should probably use the [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) form of [GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html):

```
_defaultSpeed = _player.GetComponent<CharacterMotor>().maxForwardSpeed;
```

If you call `GetComponent(typeof(T))`, you'll get a reference of type `Component`. You can cast the result into a `T`, but why bother? You can just as easily call `GetComponent<T>()` to get a reference of that type.